# Filter fetch data to checkboxes react.js

Tags: reactjs, database, filter, fetch, fetch-api

Maybe someone has an idea how to filter the data in the checkboxes.
I already have a tag filter, but I don't know how to transform it to additionally filter my prices. 
I need to filter by prices, e.g. I have a price of $ 9.99, $ 24.49 and $ 19.98 $ 20.00 - I need to make a filter: 
"<$ 10", "$ 10- $ 20", "> $ 20"

DEMO here: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sound-b3vm3?file=/src/App.js

data fetch from data.json

---

```
  function search(data) {
    return data.filter(
      (item) =>
        (filterParam === 'All' || item.tags.includes(filterParam)) &&
        (searchParam.length === 0 ||
          (searchParam.every((tag) => item.tags.includes(tag)) &&
            JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1))
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second filter and state object, and filter by that new param.

```
const [priceFilterParam, setPriceFilterParam] = useState("All");

function search(data) {
  return data.filter(
    ...
  ).filter(item => {
    const price = parseFloat(item.price.substring(1));
    return (priceFilterParam === "All") ||
      (priceFilterParam === "Low" && price <= 10) || 
      (priceFilterParam === "Medium" && price > 10 && price <= 20) ||
      (priceFilterParam === "High" && price > 20)
  })
}
```

Comment: It dosnt work  - price is not a number, it just looks like this "$9.99" it might be a problem?

Comment: made a small tweak from `parseFloat(item.price)` to `parseFloat(item.price.substring(1))`, give it another try

Comment: can you check: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-rosalind-lxoq7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: that's not enough, you need new radio/checkboxes and a new onchange call back that sets `priceFilterParam` and `searchParam`